# How to redirect BuddyPress Menu Item to a different page on the Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

So I am working on a website, and I am adding a new Menu item on my BuddyPress profile page. The Menu has been added correctly through a `bp-custom.php` page. But when I click on the Menu, I am not able to redirect it to the page I want to. The code is something like:

```
function add_gift_card() {

global $bp;

bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
    'name'                  => 'Gift Cards',
    'slug'                  => 'shop',
//  'parent_url'            => get_option('siteurl').'/shop',
//  'parent_slug'           => $bp->profile->slug,
    'screen_function'       => 'gift_card_screen',          
    'position'              => 90,
    'default_subnav_slug'   => 'shop'
) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'add_gift_card', 100 );

function gift_card_screen() {
add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'gift_card_screen_content' );
bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
}

function gift_card_screen_content() { 
echo 'Gift Cards<br/>';
}
```

How can I redirect it to a new page on the website irrespective of the root user domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the template functions, to redirect it properly. And as suggested by shanebp, the bp_core_redirect function came handy. The code now looks like this:

```
function add_gift_card() {

global $bp;

bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
    'name'                  => 'Gift Cards',
    'slug'                  => 'shop',
    'screen_function'       => 'gift_card_screen',          
    'position'              => 90,
    'default_subnav_slug'   => 'shop'
) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'add_gift_card', 100 );

function gift_card_screen() {

bp_core_redirect( get_option('siteurl').'/shop/' );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
//  'parent_url'            => get_option('siteurl').'/shop',
//  'parent_slug'           => $bp->profile->slug,
```

To this:

```
'parent_url'            => $bp->displayed_user->domain,
'parent_slug'           => $bp->profile->slug,
```

Then try this:

```
function gift_card_screen_content() { 
     bp_core_redirect( site_url( '/shop/' ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed the template function and used bp_core_redirect. It now works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is issue a HTTP header with a `Location` key and value. WordPress has a function that will do this for you.

The function you're looking for is [`wp_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect). The canonical example:

```
<?php
    wp_redirect( $location, $status );
    exit;
?>
```

It's not black magic, and basically does this:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.anyhost.com");
```

But it's best to use WordPress related functions in a WordPress environment because developers like to respond to these kinds of actions and filter various related data.